# Is there a template or something similar to draw any node in the ui panel?

Tags: python, node-editor, panel

I state that I am able to draw a UI panel with default_value etc. input nodes

But seeing that there is a widget called `template_color_ramp`
I can draw my node in this example from the UI panel

```
cr_node= C.object.active_material.node_tree.nodes['MyColRamp']
layout.template_color_ramp(cr_node, "color_ramp", expand=True)
```

Is there a widget / template to draw any node instead? For example the node of type "TEX_IMAGE" has operators to add or change images, or the Noise node has an enumproperty, Wave Texture has 3 enumproperty.

I guess I could create a proper function to determine what to show in the panel (Although I'm a bit struggling about it at the moment), I was wondering if there was something simpler in the blender API?

By the way, the nice thing about this template is that if the socket "Fac" input is connected it is not shown in the panel, nothing special, but I find it very convenient